# how can I define subdomains for a subdomain in bind?

Tags: bind, subdomain

I have a domain "example.com" with subdomain "sub1.example.com" defined as an "A" record in the bind zone file.

How can I define something like "sub2.sub1.example.com"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, if your subdomain is like:

```
sub1        IN  1H  A       192.168.1.1
```

sub2.sub1.example.com would be something like:

```
sub2.sub1   IN  1H  A       192.168.1.2
```

Comment: Depending on the type of DNS server (Thinking windows DNS here) this might create a new domain automatically underneath the parent example.com zone. So don't be suprised if you see a folder instead of an A record.

Comment: When BIND became windows DNS? :)

Comment: That's... something I completely missed, oops.